# ModalpopupExtender button click event is changing the alignment of the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopup

I have an aspx page with multiple controls.

When an image button is clicked, a modalpopup will open. In the modal popup, I have label, textbox and few buttons - Search, Add, Cancel.

When I click search button a grid will open with results matching the text box text. When ever this grid loads the alignment(All the labels and listboxes below this image control) of the page behind(aspx - mainpage) gets messed up.

There is no problem with other button click events in the modal popup.

How can I retain my table structure?

Please help. Sorry cannot post code.

Comment: Are you adding new styles to the page when you open your modal?

Comment: I got it resolved by moving all the panels of the modal popups to the bottom of the aspx page, below the table control.